# Force SSL redirect - Apache/IHS RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to set up a rewrite rule which will force all requests coming in on port 80 to use HTTPS by force.

I'm only getting my head around mod_rewrite but this is what i currently have;

```
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{REQUEST_URI}} /securePath$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1
```

In the RewriteCond securePath is the requested path (not including my domain).The full URI would be www.mydoamin.com/securePath 
In the ReWriteRule $1 is supposed to be the output from ${lowercase:%{REQUEST_URI}} in the RewriteCond

However when i restart my IHS server and attempt to hit the URL it isint forcing access through HTTPS. Any suggestions on what is wrong with these two lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^securePath/(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's just you example being broken, but you are explicitly lowercasing the incoming request path and try to match that to "/securePath" which includes a capital letter. -That is never going to match.